# CCLayerColor not working as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I try to add a layer whose all purpose is to fill the entire scene with the white color.

I try doing it as follows :

```
// Inside a cass which extends CCScene
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {                    
        // Create the flash layer on level restart
        _flashLayer = [[CCLayerColor alloc] init];
        [_flashLayer setColor:ccc3(255, 255, 255)];
        [self addChild:_flashLayer z:0];
        [_flashLayer release];        
    }

    return self;
}
```

Problem is that I get a black screen no matter how I set the color of the layer.
Another thing, if I try to create the layer as follows :

```
 _flashLayer = [[CCLayerColor alloc] initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)];
```

I get the following error :

```
Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'initWithColor:'
```

I looked in the source and everything seems to be as expected.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW other elements in the scene (other layers and sprites) appear as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

```
_flashLayer = [[CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)];
[self addChild:_flashLayer z:0];
```

or

```
// the key is to add (CCLayerColor *) to cast
// or you will meet 'incompatible type for argument' error at compile time
_flashLayer = [(CCLayerColor *)[CCLayerColor alloc] initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)];
[self addChild:_flashLayer z:0];
[_flashLayer release];
```

Comment: If you'll notice your first choice I posted and it didn't work and this still not solves the black color issue i mentioned as well

Comment: I wonder did you notice the difference from the statement in your post? You need to use the class method `layerWithColor` or **add a cast `(CCLayerColor *)`** before alloc if you want to use `initWithColor`.

Comment: Yep, tried your second choice and all works like charm. Thanks ! (still vague a bit about the first choice.. is it because alloc return CCLayer type ? and why setting the color explicitly is not working ?)

Comment: Your first method won't work because `[[CCLayerColor alloc] init]` doesn't do the correct initialization for CCLayerColor objects. CCLayerColor is a subclass of CCLayer, and it doesn't override `init` in its implementation, so the `init` you use is from CCLayer class implementation (which is not what you need). You can refer to CCLayer.m file of cocos2d-iphone to see what `initWithColor:` and `layerWithColor` actually do.

Comment: And `layerWithColor:` 's behavior is different with `initWithColor:`. So the second method you wrote in your post is not the same with the first choice in my post.

Comment: I should not take cocos2d as granted next time :)... thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion. Check the contentSize of your layer. In the cocos2d-x implementation setting contentSize changes polygon vertices to be drawn. I don't have an iPhone version of cocos2d right now, but I think it can be the same

Comment: contentSize seems to be okay ... I have version 1.0.1 but I didn't find anything related to the version

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's first code: 

`[_flashLayer setColor:ccc3(255, 255, 255)]` should be a `ccc4(255, 255, 255,255)`

So:

`_flashLayer = [[CCLayerColor alloc] initWithColor: ccc4(255,255,255,255)];`